# Angular form is always invalid

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Trying to build a simple form and it always returns invalid.  Cannot seem to figure out why.

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="user.name"
                    name="name"
                    minlength="2"
                    required
                >
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting? can you please show your component?

Comment: onSubmit(value, valid) {
        if (valid) {
            console.log(value);
        } else {
            console.log('Form is invalid');
        }
    }

Comment: console.logs Form is invalid

Comment: Found the problem...needed onSubmit({value, valid}) and only had onSubmit(value, valid)